# Set a list name in a class, using a function

Tags: python, oop

I have a class to import data from a CSV file, and a function that takes the filename and a name for the output list. I want to set the name of the self.data_name to be `self.info` using the `setattr()` function. How can I do this?

```
import csv

class import_data:

    def import_csv(self, filename_csv, data_name):


            setattr(self,data_name,0)

            datafile = open(filename_csv, 'r')
            datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
            self.data_name = []

            for row in datareader:
                self.data_name.append(row)
            print("finished importing data")

b = import_data()
b.import_csv('info.csv', 'info')
print(b.info)
```

This does not work because `b.data_name` is not `b.info`. This prints `0` instead of the imported CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to replace *all* usages  of `self.data_name` in the `import_csv()` function with calls to either `setattr()` or `getattr()` to be able to use the dynamic name.

Using `self.data_name` will use the member named `data_name`, as I suspect you've already realised, and that isn't what you want to do.

For example, try the following:

```
class import_data:
    def import_csv(self, filename_csv, data_name):

            #set dynamic named item to default value
            #not required if this will happen anyway (in this example it does)
            setattr(self,data_name,[])  

            #preparation activities
            datafile = open(filename_csv, 'r')
            datareader = csv.reader(datafile)

            #do required work using a temporary local variable
            temp = []
            for row in datareader:
                temp.append(row)

            #copy the temporary local variable into the dynamically named one
            setattr(self, data_name, temp)

            #tidy up activities
            datafile.close()
            print("finished importing data")
```

Make sure you take a look at [eumiro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661383/set-a-list-name-in-a-class-using-a-function/7661525#7661525)'s answer, which takes a better, more compact and more Pythonic approach to your specific problem using `with` and `list()`. However, the above should hopefully make it clear how you could be using `setattr()` in a wider variety of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class import_data:
    def import_csv(self, filename_csv, data_name):
        with open(filename_csv, 'r') as f:
            setattr(self, data_name, list(csv.reader(f)))
        print("finished importing data")
```

Comment: I think he wants `b.data_name` to be `b.info` and `b.info` to be the list?

Comment: @agf - the OP's last two sentences (below the code) say that `b.info` should contain the CSV file. My code does it for `b.import_csv('info.csv', 'info')`

Comment: +1, but suggest `newline=''` instead of `'r'` per Python 3 [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader) docs.